# How can you return a head from a controller action without rendering its default view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search controller in my Rails 5 app, and I would like for it to return a head with 400 status if the search term is blank, but otherwise search and render the results page.

Here is my controller...

```
def new
  search_term = search_params[:search].downcase
  head 400 and return if search_term.blank?

  @search_results = Post.where("lower(title) LIKE ? OR link LIKE ?",
                               "%#{search_term}%",
                               "%#{search_term}%").
                         order("created_at DESC").
                         paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
  if @search_results.empty?
    flash.now[:information] = "No results found"
  end
end

private

  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:search)
  end
```

I've tried adjusting the if and return syntax, but nothing seems to work. When I click the search button from the view with no search string, it just renders a blank page under the controllers path. I want it to just stay on the same page and do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Actually writing

```
params.require(:search).permit(:search)
```

makes `search` params required to be present and not be blank.

To make it work change a little bit logic behind it and don't use strong parameters (you're checking it manually):

```
search_term = params[:search]
head 400 and return if search_term.blank?
search_term.downcase!
```

Or you can take advantage of that exception, by writing instead:

```
rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing, with: :render_error

def new
  search_term = search_params[:search].downcase!
  (rest of your code)
end

protected

def render_error
  head 400
end
```

but this can be considered an anti pattern by some. However I believe it's appropriate here and actually quite explicit.

Comment: The first example doesn't solve the problem, it still renders a blank page under the search path. With the second solution the exception is never triggered, and all records are returned on the page.  There must be a way!

Comment: `it still renders a blank page under the search path` - this looks like a perfect example of sending 400 header with empty body

Comment: I read somewhere else that browsers assume that type 2 and 4 response codes will come with a new page to render. I tried using 303, etc, but no luck. I got something close to what I wanted using `render :back`, but the ux is a bit sucky. Think I'll build some Jquery and let Ajax handle it.